# How to ensure run of a thread exactly after end of running of a specifc number of other threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I have a class in C# like this:

```
public MyClass
{
   public void Start() { ... }

   public void Method_01() { ... }
   public void Method_02() { ... }
   public void Method_03() { ... }
}
```

When I call the "Start()" method, an external class start to work and will create many parallel threads that those parallel threads call the "Method_01()" and "Method_02()" form above class. after end of working of the external class, the "Method_03()" will be run in another parallel thread.

Threads of "Method_01()" or "Method_02()" are created before creation of thread of Method_03(), but there is no guaranty to end before start of thread of "Method_03()". I mean the "Method_01()" or the "Method_02()" will lost their CPU turn and the "Method_03" will get the CPU turn and will end completely.

In the "Start()" method I know the total number of threads that are supposed to create and run "Method_01" and "Method_02()". The question is that I'm searching for a way using semaphore or mutex to ensure that the first statement of "Method_03()" will be run exactly after end of all threads which are running "Method_01()" or "Method_02()".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options that come to mind are:

- Keep an array of `Thread` instances and call `Join` on all of them from `Method_03`.
- Use a single `CountdownEvent` instance and call `Wait` from `Method_03`.
- Allocate one `ManualResetEvent` for each `Method_01` or `Method_02` call and call `WaitHandle.WaitAll` on all of them from `Method_03` (this is not very scalable).

I prefer to use a `CountdownEvent` because it is a lot more versatile and is still super scalable.

```
public class MyClass
{
  private CountdownEvent m_Finished = new CountdownEvent(0);

  public void Start()
  {
    m_Finished.AddCount(); // Increment to indicate that this thread is active.

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
    {
      m_Finished.AddCount(); // Increment to indicate another active thread.
      new Thread(Method_01).Start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
    {
      m_Finished.AddCount(); // Increment to indicate another active thread.
      new Thread(Method_02).Start();
    }

    new Thread(Method_03).Start();

    m_Finished.Signal(); // Signal to indicate that this thread is done.
  }

  private void Method_01()
  {
    try
    {
      // Add your logic here.
    }
    finally
    {
      m_Finished.Signal(); // Signal to indicate that this thread is done.
    }
  }

  private void Method_02()
  {
    try
    {
      // Add your logic here.
    }
    finally
    {
      m_Finished.Signal(); // Signal to indicate that this thread is done.
    }
  }

  private void Method_03()
  {
    m_Finished.Wait(); // Wait for all signals.
    // Add your logic here.
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the call for method 3 in there. Might be confusing under the question I would assume you don't need the m_Finished.signal in the start method, but instead the call to start a method_03 thread.

Comment: Never mind, I realized why you have the m_Finished signal in there.

Comment: @Xenophile: No, you are right, not having the call for `Method_03` is confusing. I added it.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a perfect job for `Tasks`. Below I assume that `Method01` and `Method02` are allowed to run concurrently with no specific order of invocation or finishing (with no guarantee, just typed in out of memory without testing):

```
int cTaskNumber01 = 3, cTaskNumber02 = 5;
Task tMaster = new Task(() => {
    for (int tI = 0; tI < cTaskNumber01; ++tI)
        new Task(Method01, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
    for (int tI = 0; tI < cTaskNumber02; ++tI)
        new Task(Method02, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
});
// after master and its children are finished, Method03 is invoked
tMaster.ContinueWith(Method03);
// let it go...
tMaster.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a static variable `static volatile int threadRuns`, which is initialized with the number threads Method_01 and Method_02 will be run.
Then you modify each of those two methods to decrement `threadRuns` just before exit:

```
...
lock(typeof(MyClass)) {
    --threadRuns;
}
...
```

Then in the beginning of Method_03 you wait until threadRuns is 0 and then proceed:

```
while(threadRuns != 0)
   Thread.Sleep(10);
```

Did I understand the quesiton correctly?

Comment: This solution is valid, but may result in increased CPU usage and a delay depending on how long you wait between pollings.  Also, you'd want to use Interlocked.Decrement.  The -- is not thread safe.

Comment: True. Inrelocked.Decrement will work of course, but in my case I just lock on the class, so it should also work. To avoid the increase CPU usage a ManualResetEvent can be used in the Start(), which will be reset within _01 or _02 when they decrement and _03 will wait on it.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you need to do is to create a ManualResetEvent (initialized to unset) or some other WatHandle for each of Method_01 and Method_02, and then have Method_03's thread use [WaitHandle.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitall.aspx) on the set of handles.

Alternatively, if you can reference the Thread variables used to run Method_01 and Method_02, you could have Method_03's thread use Thread.Join to wait on both.  This assumes however that those threads are actually terminated when they complete execution of Method_01 and Method_02- if they are not, you need to resort to the first solution I mention.

Comment: As long as all of the threads executing Method_01 and Method_02 start before Method_03's thread starts, then either of these will work, no matter how many threads there are running _01 and _02.  That's how I read the question- did I miss something?

Comment: Also keep in mind that for my first solution they don't just need to start, they need to create their WaitHandles and add them to some set that Method_03's thread can wait on.  That's true for the increment counter solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an alternative in the Barrier class that is new in .Net 4.0. This simplifies the how you can do the signalling across multiple threads.

You could do something like the following code, but this is mostly useful when synchronizing different processing threads.

```
 public class Synchro
    {
        private Barrier _barrier;          

        public void Start(int numThreads)
        {
            _barrier = new Barrier((numThreads * 2)+1);
            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            {
                new Thread(Method1).Start();
                new Thread(Method2).Start(); 
            }
            new Thread(Method3).Start();
        }

        public void Method1()
        {
            //Do some work
            _barrier.SignalAndWait();
        }

        public void Method2()
        {
            //Do some other work.
            _barrier.SignalAndWait();
        }

        public void Method3()
        {
            _barrier.SignalAndWait();               
            //Do some other cleanup work.
        }
    }
```

I would also like to suggest that since your problem statement was quite abstract, that often actual problems that are solved using countdownevent are now better solved using the new Parallel or PLINQ capabilities. If you were actually processing a collection or something in your code, you might have something like the following.

```
 public class Synchro
    {
        public void Start(List<someClass> collection)
        {
            new Thread(()=>Method3(collection));
        }

        public void Method1(someClass)
        {
            //Do some work.               
        }

        public void Method2(someClass)
        {
            //Do some other work.                
        }

        public void Method3(List<someClass> collection)
        {
            //Do your work on each item in Parrallel threads.
            Parallel.ForEach(collection, x => { Method1(x); Method2(x); });
            //Do some work on the total collection like sorting or whatever.                
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would actually structure this a little differently so that you didn't have the start method creating the Barrier class, but this shows the concept well enough.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me the barrier class. If I did not understand wrong, the barrier class does not help me in this case because I don't want to block all my threads at the end point. Some how I want just to be notified at the end of last thread.

Comment: Brian's example of the CountDownEvent is probably your best bet. I was just showing an alternative.